# C# slider control but - music studio style

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm about to implement a slider control component in .NET that's along the lines of a music recording control.

With the timebased equalizer graph, and with the abilities of a regular slider.  How to go about this?

Comment: Are you talking about Winforms, WPF, Webforms, MVC or something completly different?

Comment: Oops, sorry - yes winforms :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys - I wasn't very explanatory in my question -- I did find this which I very much like - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/MediaSlider.aspx -- I'll customize it to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Track Bar Control from DevExpress

http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Editors/editors/TrackBarControl.xml